# Why is a trait bound present in the where clause but not in the function signature?

Tags: syntax, rust

I'm reading [`HashMap`'s `get` function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get), but I can't find the type parameter `K` in the source code.

Why does the `K` trait bound exist in the `where` clause, but not in the function signature?

```
pub fn get<Q: ?Sized>(&self, k: &Q) -> Option<&V>
    where K: Borrow<Q>,
          Q: Hash + Eq
{
    self.search(k).map(|bucket| bucket.into_refs().1)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`K` is a type parameter of `HashMap<K, V, S>` and it's introduced [at the beginning of the applicable `impl` block](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/collections/hash/map.rs.html#673):

```
impl<K, V, S> HashMap<K, V, S>
    where K: Eq + Hash,
          S: BuildHasher
```

It is applicable for the whole block, including [`get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/collections/hash/map.rs.html#1252), which adds an additional constraint, `K: Borrow<Q>`.

This way of specifying the type of `get`'s `k` might  be a bit awkward, but it enables us to e.g. do the following:

```
let mut map: HashMap<String, usize> = HashMap::new();

map.insert("herp".to_string(), 1);
map.insert("derp".to_string(), 2);

assert_eq!(map.get("herp"), Some(&1)); // we can search by &'static str (not only by a String)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `search` method in `get` method body use `K: Borrow<Q>` trait bounds so the `get` method needs the same trait bounds.
And about using `&str` or `&String` for key values in get method parameters,
It's enough to use only `&Q` type